# CodeTipper - Easily reward quality content with BitCoin, DogeCoin and LiteCoin tips!

Tags: app, api

### CodeTipper

https://codetipper.com

[image: CodeTipper Screenshot]

### About

CodeTipper provides an easy way for you to express your appreciation for the quality advice, and expert assistance that Stack Exchange users provide everyday by allowing you to send BitCoin, DogeCoin and LiteCoin tips to users.

CodeTipper also allows for you to send and receive tips via GitHub, through commits, comments, pull requests and issues.

**Using CodeTipper to send tips**

1. Connect your Stack Exchange account to CodeTipper at https://codetipper.com
2. Transfer some DogeCoin, BitCoin or LiteCoin to your unique wallet address provided.
3. Start tipping! To tip an answer, simply add a comment with the following instruction somewhere in it **+codetip [amount] [currency]**

   (For example: to send a 10 DOGE tip to the owner of the answer, you might write the following comment:
   *"That worked perfectly! Thank you - was stuck on that for days. +codetip 10 DOGE"*)
4. CodeTipper will automatically detect the tip, and update your comment with the results of the tip, as well as a notification to the recipient.

**Using CodeTipper to claim tips**

Other users can send you tips without you first requiring a CodeTipper account. When a tip is sent to you, we'll try and use StackExchange notifications to alert you to the tip (if you've already got an account, you can set an option to receive a notification by email instead).

Collecting the tip is then as simple as logging into CodeTipper with the StackExchange account that the tip was sent to, and then you are free to transfer the funds to your own wallet, or use them to tip other users!

### Screenshots

A comment containing a tip

[image: CodeTipper Screenshot]

The tip after it has been processed by CodeTipper

[image: CodeTipper Screenshot]

The tip as it appears in the CodeTipper interface.

[image: CodeTipper Screenshot]

#### License

CodeTipper is free to use, and there are no ads. If you like the service, you can opt to set an automatic donation percentage to be taken out of any tips you receive that will help support the service, or you can manually donate using the provided features.

#### Download

To get started with CodeTipper, go to https://codetipper.com.

#### Platform

CodeTipper should work on most modern desktop and mobile browsers.

### Contact

Created by Nathan Oehlman. For support, contact support@codetipper.com

Answer (score 2):

For more information, CodeTipper has now been released for StackExchange sites.

Comment: This is a demonstration of how to tip. Thanks! +codetip 10 doge [**Verified** => _@NathanOehlman please log into https://codetipper.com to claim._]

Comment: If this question was a placeholder for the CodeTipper app, then delete [that post](http://stackapps.com/q/4683/7653) and edit this question with the app details.  That is, make this no longer a placeholder.